# how to write query for records 2week wise?

Tags: sqlite

Following query I have written for fetch record week wise.

```
Select a.VPA, STRFTIME('%W',b.ActualDateTime) as Week, sum(b.Amount) as Amount 
from STransDetails as b
Join SAccount as a On a.TransactionId = b.TransactionIdT 
WHERE a.VPA = 'vpa@HDL'
Group by Week
```

but I am facing issue for write query for fetch record 2week wise.
Please help me!

Comment: What "issue" are you facing?  What have you tried?

Comment: @Strawberry, it's a sqlite query

Comment: @ScottHunter, I have did google but not found solution. If you have a solution please help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try dividing the week by 2 :-

```
Select a.VPA, STRFTIME('%W',b.ActualDateTime) / 2 as Week, sum(b.Amount) as Amount 
from STransDetails as b
Join SAccount as a On a.TransactionId = b.TransactionIdT 
WHERE a.VPA = 'vpa@HDL'
Group by Week
```